# adding data into JavaFX tableview

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to push my data that I'm getting from a RethinkDB into a JavaFx TableView, however, the changes do not appear in the tableview and I can't figure out why.

I'm pretty new to JavaFx so I hope you can help me.

Here are my classes : (I didn't include my memory classes where I save the data from the DB)

RethinkDBConnect class

```
public class RethinkDBConnect {

    public static final RethinkDB r = RethinkDB.r;
    GsonConverter con = new GsonConverter();    
    JiraTicketBody body = new JiraTicketBody();
    ViewController viewcon = new ViewController();
    TicketDataProperty tickprop = new TicketDataProperty(null, null, null, null, null, null);

    public void Connection(){

        viewcon.list.add(newTicketDataProperty
            ("test","test","test","test","test","test"));
    }
}
```

TicketDataProperty class

```
public class TicketDataProperty {

    private final SimpleStringProperty key;
    private final SimpleStringProperty prioritaet;
    private final SimpleStringProperty erstellt;
    private final SimpleStringProperty status;
    private final SimpleStringProperty zustand;
    private final SimpleStringProperty beschreibung;

    public TicketDataProperty(String key, String prioritaet, String erstellt,
            String status, String zustand, String beschreibung)
    {
        this.key = new SimpleStringProperty(key);
        this.prioritaet = new SimpleStringProperty(prioritaet);
        this.erstellt = new SimpleStringProperty(erstellt);
        this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(status);
        this.zustand = new SimpleStringProperty(zustand);
        this.beschreibung = new SimpleStringProperty(beschreibung);
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key.get();
    }

    public void setKey(String value) {
        key.set(value);
    }

    public String getPrioritaet() {
        return prioritaet.get();
    }

    public void setPrioritaet(String value) {
        prioritaet.set(value);
    }

    public String getErstellt() {
        return erstellt.get();
    }

    public void setErstellt(String value) {
        erstellt.set(value);
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status.get();
    }

    public void setStatus(String value) {
        status.set(value);
    }

    public String getZustand() {
        return zustand.get();
    }

    public void setZustand(String value) {
        zustand.set(value);
    }

    public String getBeschreibung() {
        return beschreibung.get();
    }

    public void setBeschreibung(String value) {
        beschreibung.set(value);
    }   
}
```

ViewController class

```
public class ViewController implements Initializable {

    TicketDataProperty tickdat = new TicketDataProperty(null, null, null, null, null, null);

    @FXML private TableView <TicketDataProperty> table;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> key;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> prioritaet;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> erstellt;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> status;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> zustand;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> beschreibung;

    public ObservableList<TicketDataProperty> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new TicketDataProperty("example","example","example","example","example","example")
            );

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        key.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("key"));
        prioritaet.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("prioritaet"));
        erstellt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("erstellt"));
        status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("status"));
        zustand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("zustand"));
        beschreibung.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("beschreibung"));
        table.setItems(list);
    }
}
```

GsonConverter class

```
public class GsonConverter {

    public JiraTicketBody gson(String json) 
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JiraTicketBody BodyObj = gson.fromJson(json,JiraTicketBody.class);
        return BodyObj;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Main extends Application 
{

    //ViewXML
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException 
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/ViewXML.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Ticket System Application");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try {

            //ViewXML
            launch(args);

            RethinkDBConnect obj = new RethinkDBConnect();
            obj.Connection();
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. *Never* write an empty catch block.  At the very least, put `e.printStackTrace();` in it.  Exceptions tell you what went wrong and where—never ignore them!  2. JavaFX objects must be created and modified in the application thread.  The `main` method does not run in that thread.  Move `obj.Connection()` to the `start` method of your Main class.  (There are better ways to make proper use of the JavaFX application thread, but that will suffice until you’re more experienced with JavaFX.)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! However when I move obj.Connection() to the start method of my Main class and try to start, my JavaFx window loads for some minutes displaying nothing till it crashes :/

Comment: What does “crashes” mean?  Are you getting an exception?  If so, include the *full stack trace* of that exception in your question.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't crash. It's just blank and when I click on it, it says "no response".

Comment: You need to add the data to the list in the actual controller, not to the list in some other arbitrary object of the same class as the controller. Aside from the other issues listed above, your `RethinkDbConnect` instance needs a reference to the `ViewController` instance created when you load the FXML.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, Thank you James_D, i get what you are saying but I don't know how to get this needed reference. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Create an instance of the `FXMLLoader` (instead of using the **static** `load(URL)` method), and then call `getController()` on that instance after calling `load()`. (Alternatively, of course, you could just create the `RethinkDbConnect` object in the controller, if you don't need it elsewhere, which it doesn't appear you do.) Then, in either case, just pass a reference to the list to the `RethinkDbConnect` instance.

Comment: Obviously, you still need to diagnose why your `Connection` method is hanging. I don't know what `RethinkDB` does.

Comment: Okey, sorry for being dumb, but when it comes to english programming instructions im always kinda stuck ... I created the RethinkDBConnect object and how do I pass a reference to the list now?

Comment: but my adding method is in RethinkDBConnect, so why call it in Main?

Comment: Well, in RethinkDbConnect im using the object viewcon from the class ViewController. You are saying that I have to use another object so i can add data to my list but where can i get that object from?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the list from RethinkDbConnect to the controller not the other way around... I know that you are saying the right think but I can't comprehend it, can you show me with source code what you mean?

Comment: Yea, I know that have to update the list in the actual controller and maybe you are right, that this is a bit to hard for me, but I think that if i see the source code I can understand it better, because english isn't my mother language and programming descriptions in english are hard to understand for me.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: instead of connecting to the database, replace `RethinkDBConnect` with a class that just adds some hardcoded data to the list, and [edit] your question to use that. That way you can separate out the structural issues from any issues connected to the database. (Divide and conquer.)

Comment: Okey, thank you for your help.

Comment: I actually did that before I started programming this case and it worked, thats why I struggle so hard because I don't know why this isn't working. I edited my post so the RethinkDBConnect class only passes one hardcoded row to the list, so can you tell me how to make this example work or did I understand you wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with the code you have posted.

1. As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-), `Application.launch()` blocks until the application exits. So you don't even create the `RethinkDBConnection` class until the application is in the process of closing. You should consider the `start()` method to be the entry point to the application, and should have no code other than `launch()` in the `main(...)` method. Anything you do in a JavaFX application should be done in the `start(...)` or `init(...)` methods, or in methods invoked from there, etc.

   In this case, since you don't seem to need `RethinkDBConnection` from outside the controller, I see no reason not to create `RethinkDBConnect` from the controller itself.
2. You need to update the `list` that belongs to the controller. Instead, you are creating a new object that happens to be the same class as the controller, and updating the list that belongs to that object. Obviously, that list has nothing at all to do with the table. You need to pass a reference to the actual list that is used as the backing list for the table to the `RethinkDBController` instance.

So your code should look like:

```
public class RethinkDBConnection {

    // public static final RethinkDB r = RethinkDB.r;
    // GsonConverter con = new GsonConverter();    
    // JiraTicketBody body = new JiraTicketBody();

    private final ObservableList<TicketDataProperty> dataList ;

    public RethinkDBConnection(ObservableList<TicketDataProperty> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList ;
    }

    public void connect(){

        dataList.add(new TicketDataProperty
            ("test","test","test","test","test","test"));



    }
}
```

Then in the controller you can do:

```
public class ViewController implements Initializable {


    @FXML private TableView <TicketDataProperty> table;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> key;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> prioritaet;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> erstellt;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> status;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> zustand;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> beschreibung;

    private ObservableList<TicketDataProperty> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new TicketDataProperty("example","example","example","example","example","example")
            );

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        key.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("key"));
        prioritaet.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("prioritaet"));
        erstellt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("erstellt"));
        status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("status"));
        zustand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("zustand"));
        beschreibung.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("beschreibung"));
        table.setItems(list);

        RethinkDBConnection connection = new RethinkDBConnection(list);
        connection.connect();
    }
}
```

And your `Main` class should just be:

```
public class Main extends Application 
{

    //ViewXML
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException 
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/ViewXML.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Ticket System Application");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
        
    }
}
```

If you really do need access to your `RethinkDBConnection` instance outside the controller, then modify the controller as follows:

```
public class ViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TableView <TicketDataProperty> table;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> key;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> prioritaet;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> erstellt;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> status;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> zustand;
    @FXML private TableColumn <TicketDataProperty,String> beschreibung;

    private ObservableList<TicketDataProperty> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new TicketDataProperty("example","example","example","example","example","example")
            );

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        key.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("key"));
        prioritaet.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("prioritaet"));
        erstellt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("erstellt"));
        status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("status"));
        zustand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("zustand"));
        beschreibung.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TicketDataProperty,String>("beschreibung"));
        table.setItems(list);

    }

    public ObservableList<TicketDataProperty> getDataList() {
        return list ;
    }
}
```

and use this version of `Main`:

```
public class Main extends Application 
{

    //ViewXML
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException 
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/ViewXML.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        ViewController controller = loader.getController();
        RethinkDBConnection connection = new RethinkDBConnection(controller.getDataList());
        connection.connect();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Ticket System Application");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
        
    }
}
```

Note that I renamed some classes and methods to adhere to standard [naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Comment: Thank you James, you really helped me! I appreciate it.